Having trouble with incrementing by 3, the lowerbyte would reset to 01
Im tasked to increment by 3 from 0150 to 9999 using MCU 8051
org 0000h
mov r5, #01

mov r4, #50

start:
mov a, #8

lcall cmdwr

solving:
jmp lowerbyte

kill:
ljmp end

higherbyte:
clr c

mov a, r5

inc a

mov r5, a

mov r3, a

subb a, #100 ; check if past 9999

jnc kill

mov r4, #11111110B

lowerbyte:
mov a, r4

add a, #3 ;increment by 3

mov r4, a

mov r1, a

subb a, #100

jnc higherbyte

mov a, r5

mov r3, a

It should increment the lowerbyte by 3 and when it exceeds 99 it would increment the higherbyte and would still show the sum of the previous increment at the lower byte i.e. (0599+3 = 0502), instead at certain numbers (0699+3 = 0701)

higherbyte falls through into lowerbyte .. it's unclear whether that's intentional or not. Anyway, single step the code in your debugger/simulator and see where it goes wrong.
